# Bootstrap data-toggle="modal" issue opening multiple times

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I Have developed a page where it has  a navigation bar with some buttons and hyper links when i click the login hyper link it should open the modal it's opening but giving some issue . it opening multiple times. unable to find the cause
When click the signup hyperlink it open the modal multiple times. please refer the image for how it looks.

[image: Image shows how the modal looks when i click hyper link]

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head><meta charset="utf-8" /><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" /><meta name="author" /><title>
    Home Page
</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="Styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="Styles/navbar-fixed-top.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script>        (function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3&appId=361718050699028";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


</head>
<body>

    <div class="page">
         <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>    <a href="#" 
   data-toggle="modal"
   data-target="#basicModal1">LogIn</a><li>
        <li>   <a href="#" 
   data-toggle="modal"
   data-target="#basicModal">SignUp</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
        <div class="main">

       <div class="container">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Owl Carousel - Images Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="jQuery Responsive Carousel - Owl Carusel">
    <meta name="author" content="Bartosz Wojciechowski">

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,400,300,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrapTheme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Owl Carousel Assets -->
    <link href="Scripts/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="Scripts/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Prettify -->
    <link href="assets/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet">

                                   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/ico/favicon.png">
  </head>
  <body>



    <div id="title">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="span12">
            <h1>Content with Images</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

      <div id="demo">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">

              <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
                <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl1.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl2.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl3.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl4.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl5.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl6.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl7.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl8.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="12" class="test">
  <div id="Home">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <h1>Section 1</h1>
      <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
      <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="about">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <h1>Section 2</h1>
      <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
      <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div id="contact">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <h1>Section 3</h1>
      <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
      <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>  
  </div>
  </div>



    <div id="example-info">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="span12">
            <h1>Setup</h1>
            <p>In order for the images to auto fit to slider containers use width 100% on &lt;img&gt;. Check CSS below</p>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
              <li class="active"><a href="#javascript">Javascript</a></li>
              <li><a href="#HTML">HTML</a></li>
              <li><a href="#CSS">CSS</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">

              <div class="tab-pane active" id="javascript">
<pre class="pre-show prettyprint linenums">
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

      autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds

      items : 4,
      itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
      itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]

  });

});
</pre>  

              </div>

              <div class="tab-pane" id="HTML">
<pre class="pre-show prettyprint linenums">
&lt;div id="owl-demo"&gt;

  &lt;div class="item"&gt;&lt;img src="assets/owl1.jpg" alt="Owl Image"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
  &lt;div class="item"&gt;&lt;img src="assets/owl2.jpg" alt="Owl Image"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
  &lt;div class="item"&gt;&lt;img src="assets/owl3.jpg" alt="Owl Image"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
  &lt;div class="item"&gt;&lt;img src="assets/owl4.jpg" alt="Owl Image"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
  &lt;div class="item"&gt;&lt;img src="assets/owl5.jpg" alt="Owl Image"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
  &lt;div class="item"&gt;&lt;img src="assets/owl6.jpg" alt="Owl Image"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
  &lt;div class="item"&gt;&lt;img src="assets/owl7.jpg" alt="Owl Image"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
  &lt;div class="item"&gt;&lt;img src="assets/owl8.jpg" alt="Owl Image"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;

&lt;/div&gt;
</pre>
              </div>

              <div class="tab-pane" id="CSS">
<pre class="pre-show prettyprint linenums">
#owl-demo .item{
  margin: 3px;
}
#owl-demo .item img{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
</pre>
              </div>
            </div><!--End Tab Content-->

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div id="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="span12">
            <h5>Bartosz Wojciechowski 2013 / @OwlFonk / 
            <a href="mailto:owl@owlgraphic.com?subject=Hey Owl!">email</a> / 
            <a href="../changelog.html">changelog</a> /
            <a href="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=EFSGXZS7V2U9N">donate</a> / 
            <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/" data-text="Awesome jQuery Owl Carousel Responsive Plugin" data-via="OwlFonk" data-count="none" data-hashtags="owlcarousel"></a>
            <script>
                var owldomain = window.location.hostname.indexOf("owlgraphic");
                if (owldomain !== -1) {
                    !function (d, s, id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https'; if (!d.getElementById(id)) { js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = p + '://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js'; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); } } (document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
                }
            </script>
            </h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="Scripts/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>


    <!-- Demo -->

    <style>
    #owl-demo .item{
        margin: 3px;
    }
    #owl-demo .item img{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    </style>


    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
                autoPlay: 3000,
                items: 4,
                itemsDesktop: [1199, 3],
                itemsDesktopSmall: [979, 3]
            });

        });
    </script>

    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>

    <script src="assets/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.js"></script>
      <script src="assets/js/application.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>



    </div>


        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">

    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to including bootstrap.min.js you have also included bootstrap-collapse.js (and bootstrap-transition.js and bootstrap-tab.js too).

Just retain bootstrap.min.js (it contains the other 3) and remove the other bootstrap-*.js files.

Note - you also have seem to have jQuery repeated.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly: You have two lots  and  snippets in your code.

Secondly: There is no need to call additional bootstrap JS documents as you already call the main bootstrap.min.js file.